# Centre image within a slideshow (cargocollecive)

Tags: html

[MY SITE](http://danieltuffour.com/T-E-X-T-I-L-E-S-1)

I have tried `text-align: center` on the parent div which contains the images but the images remain stuck to the left of the page.

I am completely stuck and cannot work out why the position of the img is being over-ruled and 'left: 0px' is dominant.

I want to centre the img within the parent div (shown by a black background).

Look forward to hearing from the pros!

Comment: try text-align: center ; you have a spelling mistake

Comment: Fixed this but still will not center img within dv

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The inline CSS `left: 0px` needed to be over-ridden:

```css
display: block !important;
position: absolute;
text-align: center !important;
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 80%;
```